# How are parameters being passed to this anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

I don't quite understand the convention of the following line from the code below

```
request.transformRequest = internal.transformRequest;
```

Is this actually calling the `internal.transformRequest` function, or just setting the function equal to a method of the same name in the `request` object?  I think it's calling the function because `transformRequest` is never called anywhere else in the code, but how are the parameters of `data` and `getHeaders` passed in that case?

```
internal.transformResourceUrl = function (url) {
        if (url.substr(-1) === '/')
            url = url.substr(0, url.length - 1);
        return url + '.json';
    };

    internal.transformRequest = function (data, getHeaders) {
        // If this is not an object, defer to native stringification.
        if (!angular.isObject(data)) {
            return (data === null) ? '' : data.toString();
        }

        var buffer = [];
        // Serialize each key in the object.
        for (var name in data) {
            if (!data.hasOwnProperty(name)) continue;
            var value = data[name];
            buffer.push(
                encodeURIComponent(name) +
                '=' +
                encodeURIComponent((value === null) ? '' : value )
            );
        }

        // Serialize the buffer and clean it up for transportation.
        var source = buffer
            .join('&')
            .replace(/%20/g, '+')
        ;

        return source;
    };

    internal.generateRequest = function (method, resource, data, account) {
        method = method.toUpperCase();

        if (!angular.isString(account) || account.length < 1)
            account = '_default';

        resource = 'Accounts/' +
            accounts[account] + '/' +
            internal.transformResourceUrl(resource);

        var request = {
            method: method,
            url: apiEndpoint + resource,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credentialsB64
            }
        };

        if (method === 'POST' || method === 'PUT') {
            if (data) request.data = data;
            request.transformRequest = internal.transformRequest;
            request.headers['content-type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8';
        } else if (data) {
            request.params = data;
        }
        return $http(request);
    };
```

Comment: `request.transformRequest = internal.transformRequest;` is not calling any functions. It's just setting `request.transformRequest` to point to the `internal.transformRequest` object. (Yes, functions are objects. Maybe I'm a JS noob though)

Comment: Consider the fact that `request` is being passed to `$http` - you need to look at _that_ function to see if it's calling `transformRequest`.  If that is just further wrapping the object, look at whatever function called `generateRequest`, where it's returned to.

Comment: @JamesThorpe My understanding is that $http is just a standard http request Angular object.  Would there be a scenario in which it calls a custom function?

Comment: I don't use angular, but a quick search indicates that [that is the case, yes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#transforming-requests-and-responses).

Comment: @apdm why do you think it's a custom function? It's called `transformRequest` - it's entirely reasonable to assume that, if present, the function would be called in order to...well, transform the request.

Comment: I understand now and appreciate the responses.  Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is this actually calling the internal.transformRequest function, or just setting the function equal to a method"
"I think it's calling the function because transformRequest is never called anywhere else in the code"

**How `internal.transformRequest` method get's called**

*line 7*  : `transformRequest` :method(function) is added to `internal` :object

```
internal.transformRequest = function (data, getHeaders) {
```

*line 54* : `transformRequest` propery of `request` :object is assigned to above method

```
request.transformRequest = internal.transformRequest;
```

*line 59*: `$http()` :function  is called with `request` :object who now has 
`transformRequest` :method which points to `internal.transformRequest`

```
return $http(request);
```